# Error using file config when using cache?

Tags: php

I have a config.php file:

```
define('DIRECTORY', 'http://localhost:8080/demo/');
```

And file test.php

```
include('config.php');
$file = DIRECTORY . 'cache/list.txt';
$expire = 86400; // 24h
        if(file_exists($file) && filemtime($file) > (time() - $expire)) {
            $data = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
        } else {
            $data = "test";

            $output = serialize($data);
            $fp = fopen($file, "w");
            fputs($fp, $output);
            fclose($fp);    
        }
        echo $data;
```

When I run test.php in wampserver is error is:

```
Warning: fopen(http://localhost:8080/demo/cache/list.txt) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in ...
```

But When I delete DIRECTORY is code run OK, `$file = 'cache/list.txt';`
How to fix it ?

Comment: dont fun the file commands on external urls, you should be check the file with its absolute path

Comment: fopen cannot WRITE to a url, as that'd require a POST or PUT, which it won't do by default, unless you set up a stream context in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute paths not URLs for writing.

Such as `/var/www/cache/list.txt` instead of `http://something/cache/list.txt`